# No updating on QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt

I've started this year Qt with my studies, that is something I like to use, I have improved a lot my knowledges in C++. I'm doing a long project where I'm using Snakes algorithm and I am using Qt to design the interface. I already created all the layout, and I am having a trouble not with the design but with the QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene which are not updated I don't understand why. I want to use a function to add a text on a picture by clicking on a button, and my code is compiling without errors but crashing when I clicked on the button.

Here just the parts of the code I'm using for what I want to do:

MainWindow.cpp

```
/*All includes done, the list is long*/

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ...
    QImage image1("2.jpg");

    QGraphicsPixmapItem *item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem;
    item->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image1));

    QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(item);
    //scene->addLine(QLineF(256, 256, 20, 20));
/*HERE, if I uncomment this line above, the line will be added correctly without problems*/

    QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView;
    view->setScene(scene);

    ...
    QPushButton *imageProcessing1 = new QPushButton("Image Processing 1");
    QObject::connect( imageProcessing1, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(testt()));
   ...
}

void MainWindow::testt()
{
    scene->addLine(QLineF(256, 256, 20, 20));
}
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QImage>
#include <QGraphicsPixmapItem>

class ProjectWindow;

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    QGraphicsScene *scene;


public slots:
    void runSnakes();
    void drawCircle(int x, int y);
    void testt();

};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "winimage.h"
#include "snakes.h"
#include <iostream> // standard C++ I/O
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    auto win = new MainWindow;
    win->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

So, I'd like to understand why it is crashing? Did I do wrong with the function "testt"? I mean that it's maybe not in this way I should do. I had also this problem when I was using QFileDialog to load an image, and the image was not displayed at all, and this is still not resolved, I've looked a lot of way to do, and it was not working at all.

Thank you in advance for reading my question, and for helping me. I can if it's needed, send the whole project (just the source files) by private mail.

Comment: Qt Creator is an IDE, it is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;
```

Creates the scene in a local variable. It doesn't touch `MainWindow::scene`, which remains null or uninitialized.

You then proceed to use `MainWindow::scene` in `MainWindow::testt`, and this crashes as you're either using an uninitialized pointer, or a null pointer, depending on whether you use a smart pointer or not.

All such problems would be avoided if you didn't use manual memory management for no reason. To wit:

#### Interface

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  Q_OBJECT
  QWidget m_centralWidget;
  QGridLayout m_centralLayout;
  QGraphicsScene m_scene;
  QGraphicsView m_view;
  QPushButton m_imageProcessing1;
  ...
public:
  MainWindow(QWidget * parent = 0);
  Q_SLOT void testt();
}
```

#### Implementation

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : 
    QMainWindow(parent),
    m_centralLayout(&m_centralWidget),
    m_imageProcessing1("Image Processing 1")
{
    setCentralWidget(&m_centralWidget);
    m_centralLayout.addWidget(&m_view, 0, 0);
    m_centralLayout.addWidget(&m_imageProcessing1, 1, 0);
    m_view.setScene(scene);
    connect(&m_imageProcessing1, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(testt()));
    auto item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap("2.jpg")));   
    m_scene.addItem(item);   
    ...
}

void MainWindow::testt()
{
    m_scene.addLine(QLineF(256, 256, 20, 20));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow win;
    win.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, The pointer `scene` used in `void MainWindow::testt()` is not allocated.

Change the declaration in the `MainWindow` constructor from `QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene;` to `scene = new QGraphicsScene;`

This will solve your crashing problem!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I knew the two ways to create a new widget but I missunderstand it, now I understand well. But, it means, it is better to not use local variable and to define each new widget by this way `scene = new QGraphicsScene` in order I have no problems of crash?

Well, thank you a lot to both of you! It's working, and I also resolve my problem of loading a picture on a QGraphicsView because of my bad way to define my widget. I close this subject as resolved.